# How do you say "I follow Jesus" in French?

Tags: traduction, sens, conjugaison

Here's a bit of funniness I discovered the other day.

The verb *suivre* has a first-person singular conjugation of *je suis*, which is exactly the same as "I am".

So the sentence *I follow Jesus* becomes *Je suis Jésus*, which sounds (to me, at least) like total nonsense, because you're declaring that you *are* Jesus Christ.

How do you phrase this in a less ambiguous way? What's the most common method?

> Voici un peu de drôlerie que j'ai découvert l'autre jour.
>
> Le verbe *suivre* (to follow) se conjugue à la première personne du singulier « *je suis* », ce qui est exactement le même mot que « *je suis* » comme « *être* ».
>
> Donc, la phrase « *Je suis Jésus* » a deux sens, l'un avec « *suivre* » et l'autre avec « *être* », et le deuxième sens me semble blasphématoire.
>
> Je suis certain qu'il y a une façon moins ambiguë d'exprimer cette phrase mais je ne sais pas ce que l'on utilise habituellement.

Comment: haha funny :-) Could you please describe in details what you actually mean in practice when you say "I follow Jesus"? Either in English or French, thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Certainly. "What is your religion?" "I am a Christian." "So you are a follower of Jesus Christ?" "Yes, I follow Jesus."

Comment: @JoeZ : in your example, the context gives a good indication on what you mean and which verb it is, but I like the answer from "Papa Roule" which flips the sentence : "Jesus guides me"

Comment: There actually is a famous riddle based on this ambiguity.
"Je suis mon maître, mais je ne suis pas mon maître. Qui suis-je ?"

Comment: Parfois, c'est précisément l'ambiguïté qui est recherchée.

Comment: C'est d'ailleurs tout aussi embêtant dans l'autre sens, car à chaque fois que je dis que je suis Jésus, on me répond : "moi aussi". Alors que c'est impossible puisque c'est moi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour un contemporain qui *suit* Jésus : *J'accompagne Jésus* ; éventuellement *Je me joins à ...*

Au sens spirituel : *J'obéis à ... , je me conforme à* [*aux exigences de* par exemple] ... , *je respecte les règles de ...*

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 10):

Si on veut garder le verbe *suivre* pour éviter toute ambiguïté dans ce cas là on l'emploie avec un complément, par exemple :

- Je suis les préceptes de Jésus.
- Je suis l'enseignement de Jésus.

Answer (score 6):

To the extent that "to be led by" means "to follow" in the sense you're looking for, you could consider phrases that have Jesus doing the leading/guiding instead of you doing the following, such as: **"Jesus me conduit"** ou **"Jesus me guide."**

Answer (score 6):

Je suis traducteur et ai été confronté plusieurs fois au même problème.
En cherchant sur Google la phrase "Je suis Jésus", on remarque qu'elle n'est pratiquement jamais employée au sens de "I follow Jesus".
La raison est sans doute celle-ci: le verbe "être" est beaucoup plus fréquent que le verbe "suivre". Donc, la personne qui entend ou qui lit "je suis" comprend automatiquement "I am", même si le contexte est censé faire comprendre (ensuite) "I follow". En conséquence, semble-t-il, les gens évitent de dire "je suis Jésus" (au sens "I follow") et c'est seulement dans des traductions que le problème se pose.
Solutions possibles (en plus de celles déjà proposées): je marche dans les pas de Jésus, je suis les traces de Jésus, je suis le chemin de Jésus, je me suis mis(e) à suivre Jésus.

Answer (score 4):

"Je suis un disciple de Jésus." Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une façon aussi concise qu'en anglais.