# Différence entre le verbe être et suivre à la première personne au présent de l'indicatif

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, homonymes

Cela peut sembler étrange, mais existe-t-il une manière de différencier quand est-ce le verbe être est utilisé comparativement au verbe suivre, au présent de l'indicatif.

Dans les deux cas, ça s'écrit *Je suis*, un homonyme parfait, mais dans une phrase comme :

> Je suis l'ami de Marie.

Est-ce que l'interlocuteur *est* l'ami de Marie, ou plutôt est-ce qu'il *suit* l'ami de Marie.

Comment: Although the answers to [this related question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12226/how-do-you-say-i-follow-jesus-in-french) won’t help to answer your good question about how to distinguish the two words when you hear/see them, they might, however, give you some ideas on how to work around/avoid the ambiguity when you’re doing the speaking/writing yourself (at least when Marie's son, and not just her friend, is the topic of conversation).

Comment: There are tons of these in all languages.

Answer (score 8):

Comme tu le dis, c'est un homonyme parfait. Cela veut dire qu'il n'y a pas de moyen de les différencier hors contexte.

*En principe*, les contextes où l'on trouvera ces deux mots pourraient se chevaucher. Être un grand homme et le suivre sont tous les deux possibles pour le même sujet. Mais la plupart du temps tu sauras, devineras, ou demanderas la vraie opinion de ton interlocuteur. :)

De plus, je soupçonne que la forme familière [« chuis »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/839/que-veut-dire-le-mot-chui) ne s'emploierait pas pour « suivre ».

(Pour l'homonymie en général, c'est vrai que même avec une seule phrase, il existe des cas où le sens voulu peut être repéré en examinant les accords. Par exemple, en allemand, *ist* veut dire « est » tandis que *isst* veut dire « mange », les deux se prononçant de façon identique ; mais un complément de *ist* apparaît au cas nominatif tandis que *isst* demande l'accusatif, ce qui affecte les mots qui suivent. Mais quant à « être » et « suivre », la syntaxe d'un nom complément ne change point selon le mot.)

---

P.S. Je viens de lire sur Duolingo cet avis méritoire (que je traduis ici) :

> Dans la vie réelle, il y a toujours un contexte. Ne vous inquiétez pas des malentendus.

Beaucoup d'étudiants surestiment la difficulté que produisent les homonymes. Ce n'est que dans les cours de grammaire qu'ils sont embêtants. À l'oral, même si on n'a pas compris, on peut tout simplement demander (si c'est l'autre personne qui parle) : « Tu le *suis* ou tu l'*es* cet ami ? »

Ou si c'est toi qui parle, le lien qu'a donné @PapaPoule présente bien de formulations non ambiguës !

---

D'ailleurs, des auteurs peuvent au moins jouer sur ce thème. :) En voici Sylvain Lelièvre avec la chanson « Je n'y suis pour personne » (musique de Daniel Lavoie) ; vidéo [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVPKXfNgktk), paroles [ici](http://www.paroles-musique.com/paroles-Daniel_Lavoie-Je_ny_suis_pour_personne-lyrics,p06788771) :

> Je n'y suis pour personne
>   
> et personne ne suit
>   
> qu'une chaise de plage en automne ...

Comment: À propos de « chuis ». Par exemple, dans un contexte ambigu comme *je suis une fille*, la forme « chuis une fille » **ʃɥi** n'est généralement utilisée que pour le verbe ÊTRE tandis que « j'suis une fille » **ʃsɥi** reste ambigu...

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a aucune différence entre les deux.  On a d'ailleurs une devinette jouant sur cette homographie et homophonie :

> - Si j'étais ce que je suis, je ne serais pas ce que je suis.  Qui suis-je ?

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne suis pas !

Answer (score -1):

Bonjour,

Tu écriras, je suis son ami et l'autre version c'est exactement ce que tu as marqué. Ça permet de les différencier plus facilement, de plus tout dépend de ce que tu as écrit juste avant ou après. On comprendra toujours le sens quoi qu'il arrive.

Bien cordialement.